# Why am I getting error "The type 'IReturn<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" using ServiceStack in VIsualStudio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I am running Visual Studio 2017 15.6.3.

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 DLL project which contains Request and Response classes for use with ServiceStack. The Request classes implement IReturn<>.

I have a .NET Core 2.0 console EXE project which references the .NET Standard DLL. This EXE uses a ServiceStack JsonServiceClient to send requests to a ServiceStack service. It compiles and works fine.

I added a .NET Framework 4.6.1 console EXE project which also references the .NET Standard 2.0 DLL. It has to be a Framework app because it references other DLLs which are not compatible with Core or Standard. This EXE uses a ServiceStack JsonServiceClient to send requests to a ServiceStack service exactly like the .NET Core EXE, but this program will not compile. Framework 4.6.1 is supposed to support .NET Standard 2.0 DLLs, but for some reason it has a conflict with the IReturn<> interface.

```
  var extentRequest = new ExtentRequest { ... };
  using (var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl))
  {
    return client.Post(extentRequest);
  }
```

The error returned is: "The type 'IReturn<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

I can't think of any reason why it isn't working:

1. When I look at the list of References for the project, I see ServiceStack.Interfaces and its Properties say it is version 5.0.0.0.
2. I can use "Peek Definition" within the Framework executable project code and work my way through the chain of inheritance to find IReturn<> so it knows the type.
3. All three projects use ServiceStack version 5.0.2 acquired with NuGet.
4. All projects are configured and compiled for x64.

I assume the problem is some sort of mismatch between Framework and Standard versions. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 5):

You can't share a **.NET Framework .dll** with .NET Framework dependencies in **.NET Core** or **.NET Standard** projects and vice-versa.

Most ServiceStack NuGet packages contain both .NET v4.5 and .NET Standard 2.0 builds:

- `net45` - Contains support for running **ASP.NET** Web or Self-Hosting **HttpListener** App Hosts
- `netstandard2.0` - Contains support for only running on **ASP.NET Core** App Hosts

**Only the .NET v4.5 builds** contains support for hosting on **classic ASP.NET** or SelfHost HttpListener Hosts (i.e. `AspNetRequest`/`AspNetResponse`). You **cannot** use .NET Standard builds on ServiceStack in classic ASP.NET Web projects as the builds do not physically contain the dependencies and functionality needed - which isn't available in .NET Standard 2.0 (which only covers running **ASP.NET Core** Apps).

There are 2 solutions for being able to share the same project in .NET Framework v4.6.1+ and .NET Standard / .NET Core projects:

#### Only reference .Core .NET Standard packages

To be able to share the same `.dll` with .NET Framework projects you need to either [reference the .NET Standard only `.Core` packages](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx#reference-core-packages) so that when NuGet packages are installed your **.NET v4.6.1+** project is referencing the same .NET Standard 2.0 dlls as your .NET Standard or .NET Core projects are using.

#### Create Multi-targed .NET Framework and .NET Standard 2.0 projects

The alternative is to maintain multi-targeted projects which creates both .NET Framework and .NET Standard builds. This is the approach that the [Hello Mobile Shared Gateway](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#servicestack-server-app) project uses to support both .NET Framework and Mobile .NET Standard clients and the [ServiceStack Server.Common project](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/blob/master/src/Server.Common/Server.Common.csproj) uses for the same ServiceStack Server implementation to be used in:

- [Server.NetCore](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/tree/master/src/Server.NetCore) - hosting the ServiceStack Services in a **ASP.NET Core 2.0 App**
- [Server.NetCoreFx](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/tree/master/src/Server.NetCoreFx) - hosting in a **ASP.NET Core App** on the **.NET Framework**
- [Server.AspNet](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/tree/master/src/Server.AspNet) - hosting classic **ASP.NET Framework** Web Applications
- [Server.HttpListener](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/tree/master/src/Server.HttpListener) - host in a .NET Framework Self-Hosting **HttpListener** AppHost

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am not sharing a .NET Framework DLL. I am sharing a .NET Standard DLL which contains request and response objects. I have updated the description above to make this clearer.

Comment: @PhoeniceusAgelaius the issue and solutions are the same, you **can't** use a .NET Standard project or `.dll` referencing the **ServiceStack.Client** NuGet package in a .NET Framework project, it needs to reference the `ServiceStack.Client.Core` package instead - [all it's dependencies also needs to reference `.Core` packages](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.0.0#run-aspnet-core-apps-on-the-net-framework).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the link - that explained it well.

Comment: I'm seeing this same error when attempting to upgrade a class library with a target framework of .NET 4.7.2 from Service Stack 4.5.8 to 5.5.0.  @mythz - any ideas?  I can open a new question if you need more details.