# How can I resolve ServiceStack Framework/Core conflicts when I am only using the Core version of ServiceStack components

Tags: .net-core, servicestack

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I have a Framework 4.6.1 console application referencing ServiceStack.Client.Core v5.1.0. It also references four other Standard 2.0 DLL projects in the same solution, and these projects also referencing ServiceStack.*.Core v5.1.0 assemblies. All ServiceStack packages were downloaded with NuGet.

My console app will not compile. Every line of code that tries to instantiate the JsonServiceClient throws several compile time errors:

```
using (var client = new JsonServiceClient(AppSettings.BaseUri))

The type 'IMessageProducer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
The type 'IJsonServiceClient' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
The type 'IServiceClient' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
....
```

No project in this solution references a non-Core 5.1.0 ServiceStack package. So why would I get errors asking me to reference an older non-Core ServiceStack assembly?

ADDENDUM: If I revert all the ServiceStack packages to version 5.0.2, then it compiles!

(Possibly related to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417843/why-am-i-getting-error-the-type-ireturn-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-n))

Answer (score 0):

This definitely sounds like a dependency/reference issue of which if you're running a [.NET Core App on the .NET Framework](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx) you can only reference the `.Core` NuGet packages. There's not enough info to be able to repro the issue so I'd first look at clearing your `/bin` and `/obj` folders and clearing your NuGet cache to get back to an empty slate, e.g:

```
$ nuget locals all -clear
```

If that doesn't work, use one of the existing [ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework Templates](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx) so you can start from a working configuration.

A project with minimal dependencies is [selfhost-corefx](https://github.com/NetFrameworkCoreTemplates/selfhost-corefx) which can be installed with:

Install [dotnet-new](http://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-new):

```
$ npm install -g @servicestack/cli
```

Create a project from the template:

```
$ dotnet-new selfhost-corefx ProjectName
```

Comment: Please see addendum above. Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: @PhoeniceusAgelaius No, could you repro the issue using one of the existing `-corefx` templates?