# Visual Studio .NET Standard library and .NET Framework project - NuGet dll manifest definition does not match

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I use VS 2019, I have a .NET Standard (2.0) library project named Foo (using ServiceStack NuGet package) and a main .NET Framework (4.7.2) windows service project named Bar (also using ServiceStack NuGet). Bar has a reference to Foo. Bar is a windows service and a ServiceStack REST host, Foo has the DTOs shared across solutions (it needs ServiceStack library for the [Route] attribute).

When I try to run any ServiceStack-related code in Bar, I get:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. **The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference**. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}  System.IO.FileLoadException

Despite having this entry in Bar's app.config (I use the publicKeyToken from Bar's .csproj):

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="ServiceStack.Interfaces" publicKeyToken="02c12cbda47e6587" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

How can I make those two work together?

**Edit:**

Both ServiceStack NuGet packages in Foo and Bar have version `5.5.0` (the .NET Framework's .dll "version" as seen in VS properties is `5.0.0.0`). I have tried with and without a `publicKeyToken`, I've tried mapping `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0"` and `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0"`.

The actual .dll in the output folder has this full name: `ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587`

Comment: Have you tried without `publicKeyToken`?

Comment: have you check if both Bar and Foo have the same ServiceStack.Interfaces' Nuget Package version?

Comment: it seems like the only option is to convert Foo to .NET Framework...

Comment: So it builds well but only fails when running the code? Could you share a minimal sample to reproduce it if possible :)

Comment: the dll in netstandard2.0 output dir and the one in Bar's output directory are exactly the same?

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? You can check if mythz's answer helps resolve this issue. If it works, please consider marking it as answer so that other members can easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for ["ServiceStack multi-target"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=servicestack%20multi-target) to view answers that address this issue [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49417944/85785).

In summary, if you only want to [Run ASP.NET Core Apps on the .NET Framework](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx) you can [only reference .Core packages](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx#reference-core-packages) otherwise if you want to be able to mix both .NET Standard and .NET Framework projects together in the same solution you **need to multi-target**.