# Referencing netstandard ServiceStact.redis in net48

Tags: .net, servicestack, servicestack.redis

We have a net48 project which is referencing a netstandard2.0 lib, which is in turn referencing ServiceStack.Redis.

This works fine in all our netcore3.1 app, but is causing referencing issues at runtime in net48.

We've tried binding redirects, but the error below suggests its not using the public key element?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix/match ServiceStack's primary multi-targeted packages like ServiceStack.Redis package in both .NET Framework & .NET Core ServiceStack Apps, [you need to Multi target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49417944/85785).